# Mysql Query for multi Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to make query like this:

```
$query= "SELECT a.virtuemart_category_id, 
   a.virtuemart_product_id, 
   b.product_name, 
   b.product_desc, 
   c.product_price, 
   d.virtuemart_media_id, 
   e.file_url 
   FROM   wgny6_virtuemart_product_categories a 
   LEFT JOIN wgny6_virtuemart_products_en_gb b 
          ON a.virtuemart_product_id = b.virtuemart_product_id 
   LEFT JOIN wgny6_virtuemart_product_prices c 
          ON b.virtuemart_product_id = c.virtuemart_product_id 
   LEFT JOIN wgny6_virtuemart_product_medias d 
          ON b.virtuemart_product_id = d.virtuemart_product_id 
   LEFT JOIN wgny6_virtuemart_medias e 
          ON d.virtuemart_media_id = e.virtuemart_media_id 
   WHERE  b.product_name IS NOT NULL";
```

But I want this will happen only if a.virtuemart_category_id= $id. But I can't figure out how I will add that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put extra where condition

```
 AND a.virtuemart_category_id = $id
```

at the end of your query.

**i.e.**

```
SELECT a.virtuemart_category_id,a.virtuemart_product_id,b.product_name,b.product_desc, c.product_price,d.virtuemart_media_id,e.file_url 
    FROM wgny6_virtuemart_product_categories a 
      LEFT JOIN wgny6_virtuemart_products_en_gb b ON a.virtuemart_product_id=b.virtuemart_product_id 
      LEFT JOIN  wgny6_virtuemart_product_prices c ON b.virtuemart_product_id=c.virtuemart_product_id 
      LEFT JOIN wgny6_virtuemart_product_medias d ON b.virtuemart_product_id=d.virtuemart_product_id 
      LEFT JOIN wgny6_virtuemart_medias e ON d.virtuemart_media_id=e.virtuemart_media_id 
  WHERE b.product_name IS NOT NULL AND a.virtuemart_category_id = $id
```

Comment: OK thanks ... I was putting like this AND a.virtuemart_category_id = '$id' may be this why it wasn't working. But so it will be without colon just $id ...thanks

Comment: @jibon57 pleasure to help you jibon :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ... 
FROM   ...
WHERE  b.product_name IS NOT NULL 
       AND a.virtuemart_category_id= $id // <-----------------------------------
```

If you're using PHP, make sure you're using binded parameters with prepared statements.